# 男が空き缶などに入れた唾液を女子高生の制服や頭に直接かける

Tags: grammar

With the following sentence:

> 西東京市内では昨年１２月〜今年２月、男が空き缶などに入れた唾液を女子高生の制服や頭に直接かける事件がほかに３件発生。

- Does `空き缶などに入れた` modify `唾液`?
- Does it mean `唾液` was put in an empty can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Does 空き缶などに入れた modify 唾液?

Yes.

(2) Does it mean 唾液 was put in an empty can?

No. It means "spit that was put in an empty can".